# Problem of qicharts2 p chart in Power Bi: no line shown, only dots

Tags: r, charts, powerbi

This strange issue has been bothered me over a month... I used qicharts2 to plot a p chart in Power Bi. The function works well and showing the correct p chart in R environment. But once loading the code in Power Bi, facing a strage issue that no line shown up, only the dots.

Power Bi Version: 2.73.5586.802 64-bit (September 2019)

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)

The sample data look like:

[image]

The code is quite straight forward:

```
library(qicharts2)

qic(date, error, total,
    data      = data1,
    chart     = 'p',
    y.percent = TRUE,
    title     = 'Process Control (P chart)',
    ylab      = NULL,
    xlab      = NULL,
    show.labels = TRUE
)
```

No line shown in Power Bi chart, but works fine in R...

By the way, is there any way to format the chart using ggplot2? I searched the site, "qic$data1" won't work due to "not subsettable" issue. Any other alternatives?

Comment: Yes you can use ggplot2 in power bi, I have created some charts using it

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar issue and was able to find a solution. It appears that the qic() function is inherited under ggplot(), allowing you to include a geom_line() when running R code in Power BI if no line is shown. It works for me and hope can help you as well.

```
library(qicharts2)

qic(date, error, total,
    data      = data1,
    chart     = 'p',
    y.percent = TRUE,
    title     = 'Process Control (P chart)',
    ylab      = NULL,
    xlab      = NULL,
    show.labels = TRUE
) +
geom_line()
```